# How to restrict Online Archive options for individual folders through Exchange?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, archiving

My goal is to remove the 1 year and 5 year archive options for **individual** Outlook folders for end users.

I am on https://compliance.microsoft.com/homepage > Data Lifecycle Management > Exchange (Legacy). I attempted two solutions:

1. Modify the "Default MRM Policy" by removing the 1 year and 5 year options.
2. Delete the "Personal 1 year move to archive" and "Personal 5 years move to archive" MRM Retention Tags.

In both cases I still see the 1 year and 5 year options on both the desktop client and the browser.

- Outlook Desktop application right-clicking a folder > Policy > Online Archive, I still see the 1 year and 5 year options.
- outlook.office.com > right-clicking a folder > Assign Policy, I still see the 1 year and 5 year options.

However, in both instances on outlook.office.com > View > View Settings > Retention policies, I don't see the "Personal 1 year move to archive" and "Personal 5 years move to archive" in the Retention policies list.

Answer (score 0):

It may take some time for the policy to be updated on backend (by default it takes one week).

If you would like to force/speed up this process, you can [connect to Exchange Online Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) with an Exchange admin account and run the following cmdlet:

> Start-ManagedFolderAssistant -Identity "mailbox name here"